# ErrorHandler stops traping errors in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Am sorry that the title is ambiguous but i didn't know how to describe my problem in the title,any way ,i have this part of my long code that triggers a Save dialog:

```
Line1:
Dim dlgSaveAs As Object
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog(2)
With dlgSaveAs
.InitialFileName = (CurrentProject.Path) & "\Folder" & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyy")
End With
dlgSaveAs.Show
strFilePath = dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(1)
strFileName = Right(strFilePath, Len(strFilePath) - InStrRev(strFilePath, "\"))
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=CurrentProject.Path & "\" & strFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

SaveError:
   Select Case Err.Number
   Case 1004 'if it's want to overwrite an old file and i clicked "no" or "cancel" 
      GoTo Line1 'reopen the Save Dialog
   Case 5 'if i clicked "cancel" on the Save Dialog
      rs1.Close
      Set rs1 = Nothing
      MsgBox ("Canceled")
      Exit Sub
   End Select
```

as i explained in the code,if the ErrorHandler detects an '1004' error it will reopen the Save dialog after it was closed.
Every time, the first time the error '1004' occurs the handler detects it normally,but after reopening the dialog(by the ErrorHandler),the handler stops detecting anything neither '1004' nor '5'.
Why is that ?

Comment: I believe you need to put `On error goto SaveError` after `Line:` so it gets reestablished.

Comment: thanks @Brad for replying , i thought of that too, also didn't work .thanks to Mat's Mug he found out what was wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ever heard that?

> **GOTO IS EVIL**

Well, `GoTo` is evil.

First, stick `On Error GoTo SaveError` at the top of the procedure - that's what will ensure a proper jump *on error*.

When error 1004 occurs the first time, VBA enters "error-handling mode", and enters the `SaveError` subroutine.

There are several ways to get VBA out of "error-handling mode" and back into "normal execution mode" without jumping out of the procedure you're in:

- `Resume` will re-run the statement that caused the error (watch for infinite loops here!)
- `Resume Next` will run the *next* statement after the one that caused the error
- `Resume {line label}` will jump to the specified label

Notice all of them involve the `Resume` keyword.

When you say `GoTo Line1`, you re-run the procedure, **but VBA still thinks it's handling an error**.

And an error that's raised while the runtime thinks it's handling an error will definitely not do what you expect it to do (as you've noticed).

Replace `GoTo Line1` with `Resume Line1`.

Also consider using `Exit Sub` or `Exit Function` *before* the error-handling subroutine / label, so as to only ever run that chunk of code when you're in an error state.

Lastly, consider using the `.Show` function's return value to determine if the dialog was cancelled, instead of relying on runtime errors.

Comment: Many Many Thanks, you solved my problem, and thank you again for this very useful information i didn't know all about